# "Shortcut" for Setting ListViewItem Selected Background

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm using **Anniversary Update** (**14393**).
I can use this code to set **ListViewItem** `Background`.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Name="ListViewItemBackground" Color="AntiqueWhite" />
```

Is it possible using this technique to set color for **ListViewItem** `Selected`/`PointOver` `Background`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can override the selected background brush for the ListView, so that it will use your color rather than the default. You do this by providing a ListView resource with the same key defined by the control.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelected" Color="Yellow"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemForegroundSelected" Color="LimeGreen"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="Blue"/>
    </ListView.Resources>

</ListView>
```

UWP defines global brushes for all of its controls to make theming easy. By setting the resource within the ListView.Resources collection, these changes only affect this instance of the ListView.

If you want to set the same color scheme for the page or the entire app, you can override these brushes either in the Page or App resource dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks, where I can find a reference for this topic?

Comment: Here are a good article on MSDN, but mostly you need to find the names of default brushes for controls. It helps to look at the control's template. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-styles.

Comment: Thanks, thats all I need!